# Create a div a child of another div in javascript (DOM)

Tags: javascript, html

I am having an issue making a div a child of another div.  I would like to learn how to do this in javascript.

I would like to essentially create this:

```
<body>
 <div id = "graph">
  <div id "data">
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

By using javascript.  The end goal is to create many of these over and over again.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
var graph = document.createElement('div');
graph.id = "graph";
document.body.appendChild(graph);

var barWrapper = document.createElement('div');
barWrapper.id = "data";
```

The above works with no error. When I add:

```
document.getElementbyId("graph").appendChild("data");
```

I get "Uncaught Type Error: Undefined is not a function".

From my research this seems to be everyone's suggestion.  Also, the appendChild function seems to be complete to my knowledge.  What am I missing?  Thank you in advance!!

Comment: `getElementbyId` - a typo in the post? Error message tells that this typo most likely is in the real code too.

Comment: `getElementbyId` -> `getElementById` . Also, what's up with the string here? `.appendChild("data")`.

Comment: You could use a novel technique called "debugging" to track down problems like this. For instance, copy the `document.getElementbyId` line from your code and paste it into the devtools console. When you see the "TypeError", ask yourself, what thing that needs to be a function apparently is not? The first candidate is `document.getElementbyId`, so just paste that into the console by itself, and you'll see that it's undefined. How could that be? Look at it real close, or copy it exactly as is and paste into Google, and you'll see that it's a typo for `getElementById`. Error messages have meaning

Comment: How is this not a legitimate question?  Is stackoverflow becoming another troll ground?

I want to learn javascript, not jquery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem (which is causing your type error) is you're attempting to append a string, not a reference to the child element itself.

```
var parent = document.createElement("div");
parent.id = "graph";
var child = document.createElement("div");
child.id = "data";
parent.appendChild(child);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be appending an object just like you were doing with body.

```
var parent = document.getElementById("graph");
parent.appendChild(barWrapper);
```

Edit:

You also dont need to call getElementById here. You should be able to append the child to parent then append the parent to body. Like this:

```
var graph = document.createElement('div');
graph.id = "graph";

var barWrapper = document.createElement('div');
barWrapper.id = "data";

graph.appendChild(barWrapper);
document.body.appendChild(graph);
```

Comment: You missed spotting the typo.

Comment: @torazaburo The issue was not just the typo.  Also that the user was attempting to append the string "data" to the graph element, as opposed to the child element he created.

Answer (score 1):

The error is beign caused by the typo, it should be [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById)

```
document.getElementbyId("graph")
>TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

when you fix that and execute the code you will get

```
document.getElementById("graph").appendChild("data")
>NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element is null.
```

this is because you are trying to append a string and not an actual html node. you will need to grab the element first as well

```
document.getElementById("graph").appendChild(document.getElementById("data"));
```

Since you already have references to both these objects a cleaner solution would be

```
grap.appendChild(barWrapper);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple problems

1. `document.getElementbyId("graph")` should be `document.getElementById("graph")`
2. `.appendChild("data")` should be `.appendChild(bargraph)`

This JS works:

```
var graph = document.createElement('div');
graph.id = "graph";
document.body.appendChild(graph);

var barWrapper = document.createElement('div');
barWrapper.id = "data";
document.getElementById("graph").appendChild(barWrapper);
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/hatvjete/